# Automatic Opengraph Image

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

When sharing a page on Facebook or other social network:

1. If `<meta property="og:image" content="http://url.to/image.jpg" />` is present, it is used to generate a thumbnail. That's ok.
2. If `<meta property="og:image">` is not present **but there is an image** on the page, the first image present on the HTML page is used as thumbnail. This is good as well.
3. If `<meta property="og:image">` is not present **and** there is no image on the page, then there is no thumbnail.

How to give a **default thumbnail** image with `<meta property="og:image">`, that will be used *if and only if* we are in case #3?

i.e. : this default image will be used **only** if there is no image on the page (if there is one, this image will be used instead!)

---

More generally, is there a way to tell:

*"If there is no `og:image`, use the page rendering as thumbnail (like would do the well-known http://netrenderer.com/)"*

---

What do I want to achieve: **always** have a thumbnail, regardless there is an image on the page or not.

Comment: Are you using a CMS? If so, which one? Do you have access to the backend at all?

Comment: @SebastianG.Marinescu the point is: not using a CMS. (with a CMS the question would probably be solved with a plugin). But I'm ok to use some PHP. Any idea?

Comment: But are you using dynamic data - so are we talking about many possible pages? If so, how do you process your data? Some static php files? Do you use some specific templating engine or sorts?

Comment: @SebastianG.Marinescu yes I have dynamic data (basically markdown data rendered on the fly to HTML with Parsedown)... the project is http://www.thisisvoid.org

Comment: So we are in particular talking about this index: https://github.com/josephernest/void/blob/master/index.php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to provide a fallback og:image-tag, if there is no image on the page to choose from.

I see **two general solutions**:

- *Post-Check* the page afterwards with JavaScript and append the fallback og:image-tag if no images are present *(possibly not reliable enough)*
- *Pre-Check* your content in your Backend-Parser (PHP-Controller) and deliver the response with the og:image-tag if necessary

I'm recommending to do this in the Backend.

Let's assume you have a single-file PHP-controller, where you mix logic, data and view together... 
And let's say you have all your content stored in a variable, maybe called **$pagecontent**.

If this variable would hold all upcoming content as a string, you could do something like the following inside your html-head:

```
<head>
  <!-- other code -->
  <?php 
    if (strpos($pagecontent, '<img ') === false) {
      echo '<meta property="og:image" content="http://url.to/fallback-image.jpg" />';
    }
  ?>
</head>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want always a thumbnail image by your choice to be present, than you need for the case #3 provide a default image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/YOUR_DEFAULT_image.jpg" />
```

otherwise Facebook will add or ignore image by its own decision

Comment: Yes @buzz, but I want `http://YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/YOUR_DEFAULT_image.jpg` to be a fallback image just in the case there is no other image... But I want that **if an image is present on the page**, the default fallback image is not used... How to do that?

Comment: @ Basj answer from @sebastian-g-marinescu with PHP's **strpos** function should solve your problem. Tip: Do not use **preg_match()** if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use **strpos() or strstr()** instead as they will be faster. As described here http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php